# extracting the last column using a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

The example of the data set I'm working on is:

```
ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE  ColF  ColG  ColH  ColI  ColJ  ColK  ColL  ColM
X1    5     X2    6     X3    5     X4    4     X5    5     X6    3     X7
```

The columns with numbers indicate ids, and the rest represents values etc.

I want to extract the value from the cell which falls right after the `id` 5. If you look at the sample, you can see the `id` 5 keeps repeating. I need to extract the latest value of the cell. So, in this case it should be 'X6'.

Can you help me with writing an sql query for this problem?

Thank you,
Nimish

Comment: tag the RDBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc,. ...) which ur using.

Comment: There are no cells in databases. Are you in fact using Excel?

Comment: As you say yourself, the 5 is repeating. So which 5 do you mean, to identify the following desired value?

Comment: In order to avoid the impression that you are talking a spreadsheet, please show the actual schema of the relevant table in your database. Maybe in the form "create table ...".

Comment: @Yunnosch *"the latest value"*

Comment: Without data on age, insertion date or something like that, asking for the latest/youngest one is not helpful.

Comment: the last 5 which has occurred. From the example written, I would like the colk's value to be extracted - which is X6

Comment: @Yunnosch The rightmost column that contains 5.

Comment: `select colk from mytable;` is not helping why? Would you like to give more sample data? E.g. some where the "latest 5" is in a different column?

Comment: @Yunnosch Because first you need to establish it's `colK` you want to select (because it follows `colJ` that contains the rightmost `5` in the row) (yes, it's terrible design).

Comment: @GSerg Ah of course, now I understand. Probably the "terrible design" (I have to agree) was blinding me.

Comment: For putting an answer on a solid foundation, please provide an [mcve]. I.e. a line of `create table ...` and some of `insert into ...`. It so much looks like you are talking a spreadsheet that I won't start without an MCVE.

Comment: If it was a spreadsheet, I would mentioned excel. I'm using SQL to extract the data & records. The table structure is not in my hands.

Comment: @NimishVaddiparti wht about RDMBS which u have ?

Comment: Oracle SQL developer

Comment: It is very bad practice to assume that columns will be in a certain order within your application/database/sql

Comment: please add oracle as a tag!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression and go through the columns in reverse order:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b68d/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ColA,  ColB,  ColC,  ColD,  ColE,  ColF,  ColG,  ColH,  ColI,  ColJ,  ColK,  ColL,  ColM ) As
SELECT 'X1', '5', 'X2', '6', 'X3', '5', 'X4', '4', 'X5', '5', 'X6', '3', 'X7' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN ColL = '5' THEN ColM
       WHEN ColK = '5' THEN ColL
       WHEN ColJ = '5' THEN ColK
       WHEN ColI = '5' THEN ColJ
       WHEN ColH = '5' THEN ColI
       WHEN ColG = '5' THEN ColH
       WHEN ColF = '5' THEN ColG
       WHEN ColE = '5' THEN ColF
       WHEN ColD = '5' THEN ColE
       WHEN ColC = '5' THEN ColD
       WHEN ColB = '5' THEN ColC
       WHEN ColA = '5' THEN ColB
       END AS latest
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b68d/2/0)**:

```
| LATEST |
|--------|
|     X6 |
```

Comment: Case _expression_.

Comment: @jarlh Updated, thanks - always happy to be pedantic with terminology. (Although the Oracle docs are not consistent between [SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) and [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm))

Comment: PL/SQL has a case statement as well.

Comment: when I run the query suggested by @MTO, I get the following error:

ORA-00911: invalid character
*Cause: identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual. *Action:

Comment: @NimishVaddiparti Update your question with the DDL and DML statements for your table and example data (or post your own SQLFiddle) - the SQLFiddle linked from my query shows that it works for the sample data i used but I can't comment on what error you are using as I have no way of knowing how to replicate it.

Comment: SELECT CASE 
WHEN FAC_Q = '5' THEN COIL_Q
       WHEN FAC_P = '5' THEN COIL_P
       WHEN FAC_O = '5' THEN COIL_O
       WHEN FAC_N = '5' THEN COIL_N
       WHEN FAC_M = '5' THEN COIL_M
       WHEN FAC_L = '5' THEN COIL_L
       WHEN FAC_K = '5' THEN COIL_K
       WHEN FAC_J = '5' THEN COIL_J
       WHEN FAC_I = '5' THEN COIL_I
       WHEN FAC_H = '5' THEN COIL_H
       WHEN FAC_G = '5' THEN COIL_G
       WHEN FAC_F = '5' THEN COIL_F
       WHEN FAC_E = '5' THEN COIL_E
       WHEN FAC_D = '5' THEN COIL_D
       WHEN FAC_C = '5' THEN COIL_C
       END as LATEST FROM BAF_BATCHES;

Comment: @NimishVaddiparti That does not help as I do not have your table structure (DDL statement) or sample data (DML statements). You should update **your** question with the relevant information and not post code to comments.

Answer (score 0):

If your column names are dynamic, you can Use a PL/SQL block by dynamically selecting required columns in an order. Note that here I used `ROWNUM < 2` to restrict the rows to 1. You need to use another loop if you have multiple rows in your table.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
   v_col_value    VARCHAR2 (10) := NULL;
   v_prev_value   VARCHAR2 (10) := NULL;
BEGIN
   FOR cur IN (  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                   FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
                  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TST_TAB'
               ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC)
   LOOP
      v_prev_value := v_col_value;

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'SELECT ' || cur.column_name || ' FROM TST_TAB WHERE ROWNUM < 2'
         INTO v_col_value;

      IF v_col_value = '5'
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_prev_value);

         EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```